# Imagick SVG to PNG always converts with the same font

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, export, png

I'm trying to convert a SVG string to a PNG with Imagick. It is always converted showing the same font, no matter which one is the svg code using. This is my code:

```
    $im_cells = new \Imagick();
    $im_cells->setBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $svg = $this->svgScale($this->svg, $width, $height);
    $im_cells->readImageBlob($svg);
    $im_cells->scaleImage($width, 0);
    $im_cells->setImageFormat("png32");
    $im_cells->writeImage(base_path() . "/cells.png");
```

The command "convert -list font" returns a large list, now I show those which match with the one I'm using:

```
Font: Utopia-Bold
family: Utopia
style: Normal
stretch: Normal
weight: 700
glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/ghostscript/putb.pfa
Font: Utopia-Bold-Italic
family: Utopia
style: Italic
stretch: Normal
weight: 700
glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/ghostscript/putbi.pfa
Font: Utopia-Italic
family: Utopia
style: Italic
stretch: Normal
weight: 400
glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/ghostscript/putri.pfa
Font: Utopia-Regular
family: Utopia
style: Normal
stretch: Normal
weight: 400
glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/ghostscript/putr.pfa
false
```

And I am trying to convert this SVG, which if I generate a .svg file is shown properly.

```
<svg id="svg_export" viewBox="0 0 800 600 " style=" pointer-events: none;">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="600" version="1.1">
     <svg id="svg-tree">
         <svg id="selected_cell_svg" style="fill: rgba(32, 221, 32, 0.49); stroke-width: 1px; stroke: rgb(32, 83, 32);" x="331" y="170">
             <rect id="selected_cell_shape" width="52" height="42" rx="2" ry="2" style="width: 52px; height: 42px;"></rect>
         </svg>
                         <svg id="title" x="248" y="525" height="25" width="304">
                 <text x="50%" text-anchor="middle" class="text_title_tree" fill="#532720" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;">
                     <tspan font-size="15" class="tspan_title_tree" id="tspan_title" x="50%" font-family="Utopia" y="12.5" style="font-family: Utopia;">Title</tspan>
                 </text>
             </svg>

                 <svg id="cell_1" x="373" y="467" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_1" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="9" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="2.640625" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Mary y Lora</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Barcelona</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_2" x="339" y="408" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_2" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="6" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="6.0859375" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Name</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">CARBONELL</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">19/09/1970</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Barcelona</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_3" x="407" y="408" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_3" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="6" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="6.0859375" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">María del Mar</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">GARCÍA-GALÁN</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">18/08/1973</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Barcelona</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_4" x="259" y="376" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_4" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_5" x="320" y="293" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_5" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_6" x="426" y="293" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_6" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_7" x="486" y="376" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_7" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_8" x="167" y="342" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_8" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_9" x="194" y="264" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_9" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_10" x="254" y="203" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_10" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_11" x="331" y="170" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_11" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_12" x="415" y="170" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_12" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_13" x="491" y="203" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_13" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_14" x="551" y="264" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_14" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_15" x="579" y="342" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_15" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_16" x="64" y="341" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_16" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_17" x="71" y="283" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_17" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_18" x="92" y="226" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_18" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_19" x="126" y="174" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_19" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_20" x="165" y="128" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_20" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_21" x="223" y="91" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_21" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_22" x="282" y="68" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_22" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_23" x="342" y="58" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_23" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_24" x="404" y="58" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_24" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_25" x="464" y="68" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_25" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_26" x="522" y="91" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_26" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_27" x="580" y="128" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_27" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_28" x="620" y="174" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_28" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_29" x="654" y="226" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_29" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_30" x="675" y="283" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_30" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg><svg id="cell_31" x="682" y="341" height="42" width="52"><text id="text_cell_31" class="text_cell_tree" font-size="7" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" y="3.1171875" font-family="Utopia" style="font-family: Utopia;"><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Abuelo</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">SURNAME</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">TEST</tspan><tspan x="50%" dy="1em" class="tspan_cell_tree" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="font-family: Utopia" font-family="Utopia">Fecha</tspan></text></svg></svg>
 </svg>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick can use one of 3 SVG renderers: Inkscape, RSVG delegate and its own internal MSVG/XML. The best is Inkscape. It only needs to be installed and ImageMagick will use it. RSVG is a delegate that must be installed with ImageMagick. I tested your SVG file with all 3 on IM 6.9.10.28 Q16 Mac OSX and only Inkscape produce an output, though I do not know if it is correct. The others gave error messages. Here is my result when using ImageMagick with Inkscape.

```
convert test.svg test.png
```

[image]

You can see whether ImageMagick is using RSVG or MSVG/XML by looking at the end of the line for SVG with the command:

```
convert -list format
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I get the same output as you, but I'm trying to convert it into a .png, and it always outputs with the same font, no matter which one I'm using. I'm gonna update my question to show it.